# Why data is not updated from a controller to another when set with service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I want to do is to set data from a controller to another using a service.

In my code, the service updates the data succesully, but the data doesn't get updated in the second controller

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Cotroller1">
        <p>{{test}}</p>            <!-- still value 20, after button click -->
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Cotroller2">
            <button ng-click="changeValue(30)">test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
app.service('Service', function(){
    var value = 20;

    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return value;
        },
        setValue: function(newValue){
            value = newValue;
        }
    };
});

app.controller('Cotroller1', function($scope, Service){
    $scope.test = Service.getValue();
});
app.controller('Cotroller2', function($scope, Service){
    $scope.changeValue = function(newValue){
        Service.setValue(newValue);
        alert(Service.getValue());          //proves the data was updated
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5zaqgem/1/)

Is this a good practice for what I'm trying to do?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly watch the service:

```
app.controller('Cotroller1', function($scope, Service){
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return Service.getValue()
    }, function(newVal) {
      $scope.test = newVal;
    });
});
```

Changes in a service won't propagate to a controller unless you bind changes in that service to the controller's digest cycle. `$watch` does just that.

Answer (score 2):

As long as I'm concerned, using events is the way to go. If someone thinks the opposite I would like to know why:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.service('Service', function($rootScope){
    var value = 20;

    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return value;
        },
        setValue: function(newValue){
            $rootScope.$broadcast("changeValue", newValue);
        }
    };
});

app.controller('Cotroller1', function($scope, Service){
    //$scope.test = Service.getValue();
    $scope.$on("changeValue",function(event, args){
        $scope.test = args;
    });
});

app.controller('Cotroller2', function($scope, Service){
    $scope.changeValue = function(){
        Service.setValue("12341234");
    };
});
```

Comment: Yeah the event approach is a good one too. Only thing I would consider is finding a good way to keep track of the events (for example, in an `angular.module().constant` object or something similar), or else it can get kinda hairy.